# Fields being ignored while saving to database

Tags: mongodb, angular, express

The fields profilepicpath and resume are being ignored while saving this to the database. All the other fields below it are being saved, just those two are being ignored. Database used: MongoDB.

```
var infoField = {
  profilepicpath: this.profilePicName,
  resume: this.resumeName,
  name: firstName + ',' + lastName,
  gender: optradio,
  address: { primaryaddress: primaryaddress, city: city, district: 
           district},
  dob: { year: this.userDate[0], month: this.userDate[1], day: 
       this.userDate[2] },
  skillSet: userSkillSets,
  userType : '1'
}
```

When I console the infoField profilepicpath and resume both are shown but once it is sent to the database those two fields are being ignored.

Comment: Try to use some hard coded value and see if its storing into db or not.

Comment: Also please add whatever express code you're using, or remove the tag.